# A CFG Grammar for One Language

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, regular-language, turing-machines

Suppose :

$w_1,w_2 \in \{a,b\}^∗$

and

$ L=\{w_1w_2 \mid w_1,w_2 \in \{a,b\}^* \land n_a(w_1)=n_b(w_2)\}$

$n_a$ is number of $a$'s and $n_b$ is number of $b$'s.

This is a Entrance Exam question. I think there is a typo in this question, or I'm wrong and there is a L with {a,b} and {0,1} alphabet? Any clarification by some expert?

I know this is a CFG. but I couldn't write any CFG grammar. Anyone could help me?

thanks

Comment: What are $n_a$ and $n_b$?

Comment: Still doesn't look right.  Is it $0$ and $1$ or $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Looks like this is what they meant.  Please correct in your question.  Thanks.

Comment: The same question has been posted at the same time at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29318/cfg-grammar-challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $S \rightarrow aSA \mid bS \mid \varepsilon$ and $A \rightarrow b \mid aA \mid \varepsilon$?

Disclaimer: I didn't think about this for more than ten seconds, so please check!

Comment: @Okh.Pij: I though you wanted a grammar for this?  (Yes, I think the "$0,1$" stuff was a typo.)

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.  I mixed up $a$ and $b$.  I think yours is more elegant while mine is probably a tad easier to understand.

Comment: $w_1=b$, $w_2=\varepsilon$.  $w_1$ has no $a$'s, $w_2$ has no $b$'s.  I'm leaving now.